Numpy not found in /usr/lib/python3.11, but installed in /usr/lib/python3
Not sure what happened but import numpy now fails (after Debian apt update).
$ /usr/bin/python3 -i
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

According to strace -f it is attempting to look for numpy in /usr/lib/python3.11/dist-packages and there is no numpy package, however ...
Debian apt install python3-numpy installed that package into a different /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages directory.
I ascertained that python is from /usr/bin.
What did I do wrong?
Debian 12

Can you not get around it by installing numpy in a virtualenv derived from your 3.11 install and then pip installing it ?

A transient error of Debian numpy packaging in Debian 12.1.
A simple apt update fixed this.
